# How to auto edit the post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way in WordPress to make posts edit themselves automatically at a certain date ?

For example, if we took a  post type that can expire, after it expires I want to add a warning bar at the top of the post that says that the offer is ended without deleting the whole post also without doing it manually and also putting it in a special page for ended offers is not an option.

How can i do this ? I prefer doing it my self with code rather then using a plugin.

Comment: How is it defined when the post expires? Meta field with a date (if so, which date format?), or number of days since the publish date?

Comment: yes of course with a meta field, a post is expired if the date in the meta field is equal to today's date, date format is not a problem i can edit it myself, any way i prefer d/m/Y